# cordova_plugin_file_chooser not working in same device for two different apps

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I am using cordova cli for creating android app.

I have user cordova_plugin_file_chooser

Where it given that below

Note that like a ContentProvider, the DocumentProvider authority must be unique. You should change com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents in your Manifest, as well as the LocalStorageProvider.AUTHORITY field.

By above I have update in my AndroidManifest by changing android:authorities="com.crypho.localstorage.documents" to com.12345.localstorate.documents but when I build app using cordova build android it added new instance in manifest file with existing name android:authorities="com.crypho.localstorage.documents"

Can anybody know where should I changed in the code exactly?

UPDATE:
Still not resolved the issue of provider name confict.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved issue by replacing provider authorities by ${applicationID}.Provider in `<provider>` of that specific plugin in android.json file.
Thanks